# One of many prebuilt libraries is not included on ndk-build

Tags: android, android-ndk

I'm developing an android application with some native code. I also have some native prebuilt libs that should be included in the project. First I put the prebuilt libs in the libs/armeabi folder of the project. But the problem was that these files got deleted on build.

So I googled a little bit and found that you have to include these prebuilt libraries in you Android.mk file to be copied to the libs/armeabi folder.

Here is a part of my Android.mk:

```
[...]
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := libavcodec
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libavcodec.so

include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := libavdevice
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libavdevice.so

include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := libavfilter
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libavfilter.so

include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := libavformat
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libavformat.so

include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := libavutil
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libavutil.so

include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := libmetaiosdk
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libmetaiosdk.so

include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)


include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libswscale
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libswscale.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := libswresample
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libswresample.so

include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
[EOF]
```

The problem is:
All of these files are in the same directory and all of these files get copied to the libs/armeabi folder. Except one file!
The libswscale.so does not get copied. I have no idea what's wrong here. I definitely do not have a typo in the file name.

Am I missing something. Perhaps anybody had a similar problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I did not know that the Android.mk file is proccessed **unordered**. The last missing lib was not copied because there was an error inbetween. So the mistake was that I expected the Android.mk file to be proccessed in a linear order from top to bottom. But this is not the case. The missing library was copied at the end of the build probably because of the LOCAL_MODULE naming (all libs begin with libav except the libswscale).

Hope this save other people some time (I took a while to realize it).

Comment: Only after two days it says. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Probably, `libswresample` was not added in `Android.mk` file under `LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES`.

This worked for me.